# How to serialize to JSON a list of model objects in django/python

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I am trying to serialize a list of model object defined as:

```
class AnalysisInput(models.Model):
    input_user = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    input_title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    input_date = models.DateTimeField()
    input_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I wrote a custom serializer (encoder) for json.dumps():

```
class AnalysisInputEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, AnalysisInput):
            return { "input_id" : obj.id,
                    "input_user" : obj.input_user,
                    "input_title" : obj.input_title,
                    "input_date" : obj.input_date.isoformat(),
                    "input_link" : obj.input_link }
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

When I serialize only one object, I am able to do it. When I try to serialize a list of object I get

```
[ objects..] is not JSON serializable
```

I searched but I didn't find where to work on.. I was thinking about writing a custom serializer also for list of model object.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A custom encoder is not called recursively. You are actually better off *not* using a custom encoder, and instead convert your objects to simple python types before serializing.

You could add a `as_json` or similarly named method to your model and calling that every time you need a JSON result:

```
class AnalysisInput(models.Model):
    input_user = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    input_title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    input_date = models.DateTimeField()
    input_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def as_json(self):
        return dict(
            input_id=self.id, input_user=self.input_user,
            input_title=self.input_title, 
            input_date=self.input_date.isoformat(),
            input_link=self.input_link)
```

Then in your view:

```
# one result
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result.as_json()), content_type="application/json")

# a list of results
results = [ob.as_json() for ob in resultset]
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: It works, flawlessly :).. may I ask to you why I should not use custom encoders?

Comment: @Francesco: you'd have to write something that fully recurses over all lists, tuples and mappings to find your model objects. In your views, however, you know exactly where your model objects are located already, leading to easier to maintain code. You *could* combine the two techniques, of course; [pyramid's JSON renderer supports `__json__` methods on results](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/renderers.html#serializing-custom-objects) for example.

Comment: When I try it, I get this exception > `unbound method as_json() must be called with Category instance as first argument`

Comment: @AlexJolig: you call it on actual instances of your model, not the model itself.

Comment: This is brilliant.  Martjin Pieters is the beezneez.

Comment: Looks great! Should the method name/signature be `as_dict(self)` instead since it's not really returning a json...

Comment: this is amazing!, you rock!!

Answer (score 22):

The best way I found to serialize your Django models is by using `django.core.serializers` to serialize your model list into JSON, XML, or YAML. No custom serialization code required! Documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

Here is my implementation:

lead/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    twitter_handle = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    github_handle = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

lead/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
from lead.models import Lead

def index(request):
    leads_as_json = serializers.serialize('json', Lead.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(leads_as_json, content_type='application/json')
```

The end result:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "lead.lead", "fields": {"twitter_handle": "johndoe", "name": "John Doe", "phone": "1(234)567-8910", "email": "john@doe.com", "github_handle": "johndoe"}}]
```

Comment: how to customise the response ?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution:

```
def index(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', Product.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```