# Reload the table without refreshing the page in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

Have small table that needs to be updated every 10 seconds with new data. Entire website is working in Django. JSON is parsing data into 1 table and rewriting the data every 10 seconds in database. The website is showing the data from the database. The procedure I need is to refresh the front-end table with new data every 10 seconds - it would be the AJAX I assume, can you help me write the code for it? It would not append data to the table, just keep refreshing it.

Example - The table in the database has fixed 10 rows of data and it is being refreshed by JSON. The front-end would always show 10 rows, so every 10 seconds, the table (front-end) would always show 10 rows with the new data.

Django version 1.11

Here are the python files

## views.py

```
def prices(request):
    prices = Price.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'prices.html', {'prices':prices})
```

## prices.html

```
<div class="col-md-8">
     <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>TYPE</th>
                 <th>NAME</th>
                 <th>PRODUCT</th>
                 <th>VALUE</th>                 
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         {% for price in prices %}
             <tr>
                 <td>{{ price.type }}</td>
                 <td>{{ price.name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ price.product }}</td>
                 <td>{{ price.value }}</td>
             </tr>
         {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^prices/', product_views.prices, name='prices'),
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accomplished this with Django REST Framework and AJAX with a hint above. Was not sure how to do it in the views so I used REST. By using REST I have JSON to use for AJAX. The previous answer is refreshing entire page, this one is refreshing the table in the front-end.

I cannot say if this it the best solution, but it is working great. Maybe there is a much faster one.

API

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Price

class PriceModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Price
         fields = [
             'type',
             'name',
             'product',
             'value',
         ]
```

views.py for API

```
 from rest_framework import generics
 from .serializers import PriceModelSerializer
 from .models import Price

 class PriceListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
      serializer_class = PriceModelSerializer

     def get_queryset(self):
          return Price.objects.all().order_by('sort')
```

urls.py for API

```
 urlpatterns = [
     #...other urls
     url(r'^$', PriceListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
 ]
```

template

```
 <section class="pt100 pb100">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="vertical-align">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                       <thead>
                            <tr>
                                 <th>TYPE</th>
                                 <th>NAME</th>
                                 <th>PRODUCT</th>
                                 <th>VALUE</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>

                       </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

main urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
     #...other urls
     url(r'^api/prices/', include('[LOCATION_OF_YOUR_URLS].urls', namespace='api-prices')),
 ]
```

AJAX

```
 <script>

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/prices/",
            success: function(data) {
                $("tbody").empty();
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    var priceKey = key;
                    var priceType = value.type;
                    var priceName = value.name;
                    var priceProduct = value.product;
                    var priceValue = value.value;
                    $("tbody").append(
                       "<tr><td>" + priceType + "</td><td>" + priceName + "</td><td>" + priceProduct + "</td><td>" + priceValue + "</td></tr>"
                    )
                })
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("error")
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    }, 1000)
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a django view that returns all rows in the specified table. Now create a ajax function that polls the django view (via a url) every 10 seconds.

Use jquery, you would have to include jquery cdn like this :

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">`

Now the `ajax function` (jquery ajax)

```
var updateTable = $.ajax({

                method: "GET",
                url: "prices/",


                success: function(data, textStatus, request) {

                console.log(data) 
                //update your DOM with new data recieved in **data**

            }
        });

setInterval(updateTable,10000);
```

Execute this ajax function every 10 seconds. Remember that the view will return raw html with the table. This data will be accessible in success callback function of the ajax function you wrote. Now you would have to update your DOM with the new table you got in **data** variable. Try to run console.log(data) from inside success callback to see the response by server.

Comment: That is what I am asking, I have the view that returns all the rows, it is above in the question, what I do not know how to write that ajax function to update the html front-end table, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: How can I execute that ajax function every 10 secs? I apologize, I am new to ajax, if you can update the answer with the full code that would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, this ajax call will access the entire  /prices/ page so the data are entire HTML page with all elements not only the price table, I would like to just grab these data from the views.py "prices = Price.objects.all().order_by('id')" and update the table, with that ajax call it is outputting entire page with all elements that I am having on that page that is so many elements...

Comment: in that case you do not need to use a template you can directly return a json response via view instead of returning a render object.

`from django.http import JsonResponse` and in the view do

then serialize the model object into json - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031058/how-to-serialize-to-json-a-list-of-model-objects-in-django-python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142414/discussion-between-rentgeeen-and-pradeep-saini).