# How to update a Datatable via Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, datatable

I have a table that displays the content from a model whenever someone accesses the URL `/project_page`.

On that page, the user can add files and I would like the table to be updated in real-time without having to constantly refresh.

For that purpose, I have tried to implement an Ajax function that updates the table content every few seconds. Since it is something that was suggested a few years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574031/reload-the-table-without-refreshing-the-page-in-django)

I think the function is implemented and I receive the `data` properly in the Ajax success function but I don't know how to 'inject it' to the table.

[image]

I would also like to know if there is a more optimal or pythonic way to achieve this result.

`urls.py`

```
path('project_page_ajax/', views.project_page_ajax, name='project_page_ajax'),
```

`views.py`

```
@login_required
def project_page(request):
    
    context = {}
    context['nbar'] = 'projects'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_hist = form.save(commit=False)
            file_hist.user = request.user
            # file is saved
            file_hist.save()
            file_hist_results = FileHistory.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
            context['file_hist_results'] = file_hist_results
            print(type(context['file_hist_results']))
            return render(request, 'project_page.html', context)
        print (form.errors)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    file_hist_results = FileHistory.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    context['file_hist_results'] = file_hist_results
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'project_page.html', context)

@login_required
def project_page_ajax(request):
    response = dict()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        file_hist_results = FileHistory.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).values()
        #response.update({'file_hist_results': file_hist_results})
        return JsonResponse({"file_hist_results": list(file_hist_results)})
    return HttpResponse('')
```

`project_page.html` (JS PART)

```
var intervalID = setInterval(updateTable, 10000);

function updateTable()
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/project_page_ajax/",
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            console.log(data); 
        }
    });
}
```

`project_page.html`(HTML PART)

```
<table id="ittFileUploadTable" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ittLineItemsTh">
        <th style="text-align:center;">File Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Submitted</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Updated</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">User</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for histfiles in file_hist_results %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ histfiles.filename }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.uploaded }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.updated }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.user }}</td>
        <td>
        <button id="delete-itt-file" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"></path>
        </svg>
        </button>
        </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try to update your tag this question is more related to javascript or jquery

Comment: JS added, as suggested ;)

Comment: what is the project_page url name ? because inside the `form.is_valid()` it is better to redirect the user instead of rendering that a html of the current page.

Comment: `path('project_page', views.project_page, name='project_page'),`

Comment: Don't use jQuery Ajax, the Ajax function that comes with Datatables is much better suited for this task. https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax Return JSON data from your server and configure how you want your table to look in the DataTables options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

As @mark_b sugested, I used the datatables Ajax instead of jQuery AJAX

Now it works, here is my code:

```
$('#ittFileUploadTable').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    autowidth: false,
    destroy: true,
    deferRender: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/project_page_ajax/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataSrc: ""
    },
    columns: [
        {"data": "fields.filename"},
        {"data": "fields.uploaded"},
        {"data": "fields.updated"},
        {"data": "fields.user"},
        {"data": "pk"},
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        { className: 'text-center', targets: [1] },
        {
            targets: [0],
            class: 'text-center',
            orderable: false,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                var buttons = '<a href="/media/'+data+'" target="_blank">'+data+'</a>';
                return buttons;
            }
        },
        {
            targets: [-1],
            class: 'text-center',
            orderable: false,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                var buttons = '<form method="post" action="delete_file/'+data+'/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="white" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/></svg></button></form>';
                return buttons;
            }
        },
    ],
    order: [
        [0, 'asc']
    ],
    "pagingType": "numbers",
    dom: 'rt'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this question is more related to javascript.but here is my idea how you can solve this with partial_html.This is just an idea how you can do it but maybe a javascript guy will come with a beautifull answer ))).
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect 
@login_required
def project_page(request):
    
    context = {}
    context['nbar'] = 'projects'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_hist = form.save(commit=False)
            file_hist.user = request.user
            # file is saved
            file_hist.save()
            return redirect('project_page')
        print (form.errors)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    file_hist_results = FileHistory.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    context['file_hist_results'] = file_hist_results
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'project_page.html', context)

@login_required
def project_page_ajax(request):
    response = dict()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        file_hist_results = FileHistory.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).values()
        return render(request, 'partial_page.html', {'file_hist_results':file_hist_results})
```

project_page.html

```
<table id="ittFileUploadTable" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ittLineItemsTh">
        <th style="text-align:center;">File Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Submitted</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Updated</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">User</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for histfiles in file_hist_results %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ histfiles.filename }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.uploaded }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.updated }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.user }}</td>
        <td>
        <button id="delete-itt-file" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"></path>
        </svg>
        </button>
        </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

partial_page.html(just a simple html do not put any body or head tag  just this create that file with only this)

```
<table id="ittFileUploadTable" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ittLineItemsTh">
        <th style="text-align:center;">File Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Submitted</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Updated</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">User</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for histfiles in file_hist_results %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ histfiles.filename }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.uploaded }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.updated }}</td>
        <td>{{ histfiles.user }}</td>
        <td>
        <button id="delete-itt-file" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"></path>
        </svg>
        </button>
        </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
var intervalID = setInterval(updateTable, 10000);

function updateTable()
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/project_page_ajax/",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#ittFileUploadTable").hide(); // first hide the current table
            $("#ittFileUploadTable").append(response); // and append the data
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got your point! but I don't think hiding and showing is a good idea, in this case, the user cannot notice that the table 'disappears' even for less than 1 millisecond. Also, I can not create a new HTML file. I think this question is more related to Datatables API for Ajax than JS itself, but IDK how to hook it up: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: @Cheknov `.hide()` default duration is `400ms` i do not think the user will notice it.6 months ago i had the same problem i was building a chat app where i need something like this to show the message history and it works well Users did not even notice it but after for database performance i changed it for `django-channels`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution largely depends on what the JSON response is.

## HTML

If your response is the actual HTML chunk to be displayed, looking somewhat like this:

```
<tr><!-- Some tds --></tr>
<tr><!-- Some tds --></tr>
<tr><!-- Some tds --></tr>
<!-- ... -->
<tr><!-- Some tds --></tr>
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
document.querySelector("#ittFileUploadTable tbody").innerHTML = yourTemplate;
```

## JSON

If your data is JSON, then it would be great to create a template function, like this one:

```
function fileUploadRecordTemplate(record) {
    return  `
        <td>record.filename</td>
        <td>record.uploaded</td>
        <td>record.updated</td>
        <td>record.user</td>
        <td>
            <button id="delete-itt-file" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </td>
    `;
}
```

And hydrate your `tbody` like this:

```
let output = [];
for (let record of data) output.push(fileUploadRecordTemplate(record));
document.querySelector("#ittFileUploadTable tbody").innerHTML = yourTemplate;
```

## Fiddle

```js
let index = 1;

//t1

function updateT1() {
    //We generate some HTML, but if you get an HTML from server-side, then you can
    //skip this part
    let template = "";
    let rows = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1rows").value);
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        template += `
            <tr>
                <td>${index++}</td>
                <td>${index++}</td>
                <td>${index++}</td>
                <td>${index++}</td>
            </tr>
        `;
    }
    //This is the actual operation which refreshes the HTML
    document.querySelector("#t1 > tbody").innerHTML = template;
}

//t2
function fileUploadRecordTemplate(record) {
    return  `
       <tr>
        <td>${record.filename}</td>
        <td>${record.uploaded}</td>
        <td>${record.updated}</td>
        <td>${record.user}</td>
        <td>
            <button id="delete-itt-file" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </td>
       </tr>
    `;
}

function updateT2() {
    let rows = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2rows").value);
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        data.push({
            filename: index++,
            uploaded: index++,
            updated: index++,
            user: index++
        });
    }
    
    let output = [];
    for (let record of data) output.push(fileUploadRecordTemplate(record));
    document.querySelector("#t2 tbody").innerHTML = output.join("");
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
    <thead>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
        <th>Fourth</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

Number of rows: <input type="number" value="4" id="t1rows"><input type="button" value="OK" onclick="updateT1()">

<table id="t2">
    <thead>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
        <th>Fourth</th>
        <th>Fifth</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

Number of rows: <input type="number" value="4" id="t2rows"><input type="button" value="OK" onclick="updateT2()">
```