# How do I (safely) send a Python object to my Flask API?

Tags: python, json, scikit-learn, pickle

I am currently trying to build a Flask Web API that is able to receive a python object in a POST-request.

I am using Python 3.7.1 for creating the request and Python 2.7 for running the API. The API is set up to run on my local machine. The object I am trying to send to my API is a `RandomForestClassifier` object from `sklearn.ensemble`, but this could be any of a wide variety of object types.

So far I have tried to `json.dumps()` my object, but this object is not JSON serializable. I have also tried to `pickle.dumps()` my object, but this caused an error when trying to load the object on the API side. Also, since the API will receive requests from anonymous users, I am worried about performing a `pickle.loads()` on a possibly malicious object.

Is this a grounded worry? And if so, what is the best way to send any python object in a POST request?

The script performing the POST request:

```
import requests
import pickle

url = "http://localhost:5000/flask-api-function"

# the object I want to send is the 'model' object
data = pickle.dumps(model)

r = requests.post(url,data=data)
```

The Flask API:

```
@app.route('/flask-api-function', methods=['POST'])
def flask_api_function():

  model = pickle.loads(request.get_data())
```

This setup actually causes an error when trying to decode the data with pickle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/larssuanet/Documents/enjins/dscs/flask_api.py", line 39, in store_model
model = pickle.loads(request.get_data())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 886, in load_proto
raise ValueError, "unsupported pickle protocol: %d" % proto
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

Is there a nice and safe way to do is?

Comment: don't send the actual object, its bad practice, and probably will get you in a never ending maintenance fire fighting. see if you can send a representation of them, and reconstruct them on the other side.. also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031058/how-to-serialize-to-json-a-list-of-model-objects-in-django-python

Comment: Any suggestions on how someone could go about doing that when they want to support a wide variety of objects? I feel like there should be an easier way to do this without having to write logic for reconstructing every single object-type you want to support.

Comment: in python everything is an object... can you be more specific? try to serialize your objects into JSON, thats a good place to start

Comment: As you can see I have tried that with the `RandomForestClassifier` object, and this object is not serializable. I don't need a solution for this specific object though, I am looking for a clean way to serialize a wide variety of objects (specifically ML models).

Comment: @Urban48 but not all objects are JSON serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pickle the object in python 3, pass the protocol keyword and set it to 2. This will ensure that it will work on python 2.

```
import requests
import pickle

url = "http://localhost:5000/flask-api-function"

# the object I want to send is the 'model' object
data = pickle.dumps(model,protocol=2)

r = requests.post(url,data=data)
```

Generally I would try to find a way to serialize the object into JSON since pickle has major security risks

Comment: Thanks, this will solve my error for now. But like you said, I will still be looking out for a more secure way to do this.